# Meteor JS tutorial - sessions are reactive?

Tags: javascript, session, meteor

I am working through the Meteor tutorial on the meteor site.

I am confused about Sessions being reactive components as explained in [step 8](https://www.meteor.com/try/8)

I think that the tutorial means that clicking on hide checkbox should hide the completed tasks ACROSS ALL connected clients since sessions are reactive,is that true?

Because when I check the `Hide Completed Tasks` in a client browser, only that client's display hides the completed task.

Should this not automatically happen in the other browser?

**NOTE** I have both Chrome and Firefox open and connected, but `Hide Completed Tasks` works independently and is not synchronized across the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Session is the same way, but is not synced with the server like
>   collections are

like the document says.

So if you open the console on chrome and type `Session.get("hideCompleted");` you will get `undefined`, thats because the state of the Session on Google chrome doesn't exist on Mozilla.

**sessions are reactive?**? yes Sessions are reactive, thats means that Sessions can change the state from a template an re-render it.

Sessions are god to do changes on the Current Template instance,again like the document says.

> This makes Session a convenient place to store temporary UI state like
>   the checkbox above